# .htaccess rewrite subfolders to remove /index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some htaccess rules which rewrite friendly URLs. Everything is working apart from one thing.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

This is a site with language subfolders, e.g.:

`/fr/about.html`

`/en/about.html`

With the above htaccess rules these urls come out like:

`/fr/about`

`/en/about`

However this also means my index pages URLs look like:

`/fr/index`

`/en/index`

What I would like, is for /index the URL looks like

`/fr`

`/en`

Which would mean they respect the trailing slash part of my above htaccess but remove `index` from the URL.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add (before `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^`...):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*?)/index(\.html)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```